# Get the first given symbol from the word counting from the back

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a beginner in VBA and need some help with my school assignment.

```
Function CountfromBack(tekst As String, sümbol As String) As Integer
    CountfromBack = 0
    lengthie = Len(tekst)
    For i = 1 To lengthie
        s = Mid((tekst), i, 1)
        If s = sümbol Then
            CountfromBack = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    CountfromBack = (lengthie - CountfromBack + 1)
    End Function
```

Here is what the function currently does. for the text in B9 and the symbol "e" it gives me the answer 6, but it should be 1, considering I'm looking for the first given symbol reading from the back. Also, if the symbol isn't in the cell, how should I return 0?

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/491edb81d87749407569832b2c634802.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate from the last letter to the first:

```
Function CountfromBack(tekst As String, sümbol As String) As Integer
    Dim lengthie as Long, i as Long, s as String
    CountfromBack = 0
    lengthie = Len(tekst)
    For i = lengthie To 1 Step -1
        s = Mid((tekst), i, 1)
        If s = sümbol Then
            CountfromBack = lengthie - i + 1
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i

End Function
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could just use VBA functions to do the work:

```
Function CountfromBack(tekst As String, sümbol As String) As Integer
    CountfromBack = InStr(StrReverse(tekst), sümbol)
End Function
```

(But I suggest you go with [Scott's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41048429/6535336) because you did at least part of the work toward that solution.)